# Ionic2: get image form URL and save to native storage

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

Let's say I have a JSON object containing users' profile including firstname, lastname,..., and profileUrl from a web API. I've already saved the text data using Sqlite, and now I want to save those images in native storage and put the file path into the sqlite database replacing the profileUrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` for that. There is even an Ionic Native wrapper available: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/

Example:

```
download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```